# Validate the data entry in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I need to make validations in the data entry of my textFields in netbeans. Please tell me a suitable method to do that. That will be a big help.I don't know how to set the validation in textFields in GUI forms.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just [Google it](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=set+the+validation+in+textFields+in+netbeans&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=U4B4WIvSGYzevASkpqLYAg#q=set+the+validation+in+textField+in+netbeans) and you will find many [results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=set+the+validation+in+textFields+in+netbeans&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=U4B4WIvSGYzevASkpqLYAg#q=validations+in+the+data+entry+of+textField+in+netbeans). Also take a look [here](http://w.planetnetbeans.org/topic53794.html).